# Number of execution is equal to the number of rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having a query in which number of execution is equal to the number of rows in the table.
Anyone knows any possible reason for that as a result the clustered index seek %age is very high.

I have update the Stats for the Tables.But still no benefit.

```
  select @AdditionalBillToNumericValue = cast(ab_vnum as int)  from #table1     
             inner join table4 on ab_btid = ay_bt and  ab_type = 'SRVGRP'     

             if(@AdditionalBillToNumericValue is not null or @AdditionalBillToNumericValue <> '')     
             begin     
             select distinct     
             fs.sv_pkey     
            , fs.sv_id     
            , fs.sv_desc     
            ,ISNULL( fs.sv_ehr,0) as sv_ehr     
            ,ISNULL( fs.sv_emn,0) as sv_emn     
            ,ISNULL( fs.sv_lhr,0) as sv_lhr     
            ,ISNULL( fs.sv_lmn,0)  as sv_lmn  
            ,(case when #table1.fh_sv = fs.sv_id then 1 else 0 end) IsDefault 
            from table3  fr
            inner join table4 ab on ab.ab_vnum = fr.sr_sgpkey 
            inner join table5 fs   on fr.sr_svpkey = fs.sv_pkey   or fs.sv_pkey =  @ServiceWindowKey                      
            inner join #table1  on ab.ab_btid = #table1.ay_bt 
            AND ab.ab_type = 'SRVGRP'   
            end     
            else     
            begin     
            select      
           fs.sv_pkey     
            , fs.sv_id     
            , fs.sv_desc      
            ,ISNULL(sv_ehr,0) as sv_ehr     
            ,ISNULL(sv_emn,0) as sv_emn     
            ,ISNULL(sv_lhr,0) as sv_lhr     
            ,ISNULL(sv_lmn,0) as sv_lmn  
            ,(case when #table1.fh_sv = fs.sv_id then 1 else 0 end) IsDefault 
           from table3  fr
            inner join table4 ab  on ab.ab_vnum = fr.sr_sgpkey 
            inner join table5 fs  on fr.sr_svpkey = fs.sv_pkey   or fs.sv_pkey =  @ServiceWindowKey                     
            LEFT join #table1 with(nolock) on ab.ab_btid = #table1.ay_bt     
             where ab.ab_type = 'SRVGRP'     


             Please Verify where we are having the join with table5 it is getting the issue.
             In Join Both are having int datatype.
```

Comment: How can anyone answer this? You haven't posted that query. If you have a loop that executes 1000 inserts or selects, you'll get 1000 executions.

Comment: Sorry,Please Check now

Comment: Unrelated, but what datatype is @AdditionalBillToNumericValue? You set it with a cast to int, but you compare it to a string. So which is it?